# Get data from installed android app

Tags: android, sqlite, backup

I recently wrote and installed an Android app on my device. The app wrote data to the local SQL database and uploaded this data to my webserver. But due to network problems, there are a few records that were skipped, so they aren't on my webserver.
Now i want to get those rows (or my full SQL database) from my android device. But my question is how? 
If I write a new version of my app and reinstall it, then all my data will be lost.
Isn't there a way to access my SQL database without losing my data?

My device is not rooted, so those backup app's won't work...

Answer (score 0):

You may get access using [DDMS](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/ddms.html).

Comment: my device is not rooted, so i can't see a thing in the data folder... Or is there another way to access the data folder?

Comment: Ok. Why you think that you will lose your data when updating your App? Normally the DB will not be touched if you not force Android to do it using something like a onDBUpgrade method. So just add a new capability to your app enabling you to receive the required data. Maybe I miss something and I need some clarification!?

Comment: i forgot to mention that i don't have the original signing. So when i try to install a second version of the app, android doesn't like that :)